# NHibernate dummy data

Tags: nhibernate, dummy-data

Are there any tools such as http://www.generatedata.com/ which will generate dummy data for NHibernate mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/) to get some test data and save it.

Comment: +1 for AutoPoco--fantastic little library to dummy up objects for testing.

Answer (score 0):

AutoFixture (http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) is quite useful.